# Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, sfsafariviewcontroller

I use the Shopify Mobile Buy SDK for iOS and I can't get a callback from their payment web view. For some reason the warnings:

```
2016-11-25 21:17:25.945267 Drool[3328:799969] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

2016-11-25 21:17:25.977316 Drool[3328:799969] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service

2016-11-25 21:17:26.105947 Drool[3328:799969] [App] if we're in the real pre-commit handler we can't actually add any new fences due to CA restriction
```

keep showing up and I have no idea why this is happening and if this is the cause of this problem, do any of you know what this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set value `@"false"` for cookie property `@"HttpOnly"`, just like this :

```
 NSHTTPCookie *cookieWID = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             @"wid" ,NSHTTPCookieName, 
                             WID,NSHTTPCookieValue,
                             @"www.google.com",NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                             @"",NSHTTPCookiePath,
                             @"false",@"HttpOnly",
                             nil]];
```

Comment: Watch out for putting [ HttpOnly: false ] unless the cookieValue is not vulnerable data  
https://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/

Answer (score 3):

You may need to allow for App Transport Security to access the resource. Try modifying your app's `Info.plist` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http).

Answer (score 2):

if this issue occurs on a sim for anybody, I think it's an issue with JSON parsing in the cache of the xcode simulators.  Solved by "In the simulator, choose iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings".  A more complete solution can be found here https://gist.github.com/riosc/4539602

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issues, which only appear on iOS 10.2, that is so bad. The html cannot receive the value I passed use cookie

Comment: Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service happens in 10.1 as well, this is not a 10.2 only issue

Comment: I got the same logs in iOS 10.3. Do you get any solution?

Comment: I have the same issue with iOS 13. Did you get some solution?