# Swift4 - WkwebView warning of Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a log when I load `youtube` URL in `WKWebView`.
I have searched the same title of my question in `stackOverFlow`.
But it didn't work for me.
What's wrong with my code?
And I use `swift4` & `xcode9.2`.
Thanks.

Transport also set true.
[image: open]

Warning like this:

> Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

var videoId: String = ""
var videoTitle: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    loadUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadUI() {

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    naviSetting()
    webViewSetting()
}

func naviSetting() {

    self.title = videoTitle
}

func webViewSetting() {

    let webview = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))

    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(self.videoId)")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webview.load(request)
    self.view.addSubview(webview)
}
}
```

Comment: Did you see this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585980/com-apple-webkit-webcontent-drops-113-error-could-not-find-specified-service

Comment: Yes, And it seems not work for me.

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx Please check my Answer.

Comment: @tolerate＿Me_Thx Please accept my answer if you have fixed your error. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to encode parameter and Its working fine for me. Please check below code.

```
var wkWebView = WKWebView()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    self.wkWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.wkWebView.frame =  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.wkWebView.frame.size.width, height: self.wkWebView.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(wkWebView)

    loadUrl()
}
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    self.wkWebView.frame =  CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.wkWebView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
}
func loadUrl()
{
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    let url_join = "v=1p38GWfCIhQ"

    let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?")
    var myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
    myRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    myRequest.httpBody = url_join.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    wkWebView.load(myRequest)
}
```

I hope It will also work for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

For me this Code worked fine.
Notice, I Used http:// and not https://. 
But you already have set the settings for http:// to work.[image]

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
private let url = URL(string: "http://www.google.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```