# Running a headless WKWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, safari

Apple is requiring all Safari extensions to switch over to "Safari App Extensions" which specifies the backend be written in Swift instead of JavaScript.

To reduce rewriting and duplicating code as much as possible I'd like to run a headless WKWebView that runs my current JavaScript code and have Swift act as a bridge to/from the WKWebView JavaScript. (We can't use the JavaScriptCore module because we require WebKit apis like `Window`, `XMLHttpRequest`, `localstorage`, etc)

Currently I'm getting the following errors when trying to load the WKWebView as headless and I think they have to do with the fact that I'm not adding the view as a subview to anything. see [com.apple.WebKit.WebContent drops 113 error: Could not find specified service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585980/com-apple-webkit-webcontent-drops-113-error-could-not-find-specified-service)

`2018-12-06 17:36:28.464054-0800 Extension[12768:12452197] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
2018-12-06 17:36:28.490149-0800 Extension[12768:12452197] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service`

If anyone has any experience with Swift, WKWebView, Safari App Extensions, etc. your advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for reading!