# React-Native app built using Expo is working fine on simulator on device (iOS) threw Expo, but crashes when running using TestFlight

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, testflight

In the logs, I see this error:

> failed to get process exit details for UIKitApplication:com.abc.www[8bae][rb-legacy] : Could not find specified service (113)

Working fine when running using Expo (on both simulator and device)
Crashes on Testflight with the above error...

Has anyone came across this kind of issue?

Comment: Did you follow the publishing docs by expo? 
https://docs.expo.io/workflow/publishing/

Comment: @AviLevin, we are not using expo, Still getting same error.

Comment: @Yoganand have you tried this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585980/com-apple-webkit-webcontent-drops-113-error-could-not-find-specified-service