# How to use the LinkPresentation Framework inside a Widget in SwiftUI to show an urlImage preview?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is an example code for a WidgetExtension that should show the link preview image retrieved using the LinkPresentation.  I am guessing the widgets dont load url data directly but need to be somehow fetched using the geTimeline and defined there somehow? How is it done?

Using the standard widget template in Xcode just adding the Metadata

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import LinkPresentation

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}

struct LinkPresentationWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        //Text(entry.date, style: .time)
        VStack{
            MetadataView(vm: LinkViewModel(link: "https://www.wsj.com/articles/global-stock-markets-dow-update-03-03-2021-11614761029?mod=markets_lead_pos1"))
        }
    }
}




class LinkViewModel : ObservableObject {
    let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
    
    @Published var metadata: LPLinkMetadata?
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    init(link : String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else {
            return
        }
        metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                assertionFailure("Error")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.metadata = metadata
            }
            guard let imageProvider = metadata?.imageProvider else { return }
            imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
                guard error == nil else {
                    // handle error
                    return
                }
                if let image = image as? UIImage {
                    // do something with image
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.image = image
                    }
                } else {
                    print("no image available")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MetadataView : View {
    @StateObject var vm : LinkViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let uiImage = vm.image {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    //.scaledToFill()
                    //.clipped()
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK WidgetKit does not observe `View`s, but only render them once and discard them afterwards. Thus your approach of having an `@StateObject` doesn't work as WidgetKit has already discarded the View when your request returns.

As you already guessed you have to do every asynchronous task inside of either `getSnapshot` or `getTimeline`.

Below is a minimal working example reusing some of your code. Of course you might want to adapt configuration of the url, error handling and timeline-strategy according to your needs.

Note that I don't know if any of this is considered best practice...I only know it works :)

```swift
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Intents
import LinkPresentation

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: ConfigurationIntent(), image: UIImage(systemName: "wifi.slash"))
    }

    func getSnapshot(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        fetchImage(for: "https://www.wsj.com/articles/global-stock-markets-dow-update-03-03-2021-11614761029?mod=markets_lead_pos1", calling: { image in
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date(), configuration: configuration, image: image)
            completion(entry)
        })
    }

    func getTimeline(for configuration: ConfigurationIntent, in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        getSnapshot(for: configuration, in: context, completion: { entry in
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy: .after(Date().advanced(by: 3600)))
            completion(timeline)
        })
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
    let image: UIImage?
}

struct WidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        if let image = entry.image {
            Image(uiImage: image).resizable().scaledToFill()
        } else {
            Text("Could not load image...")
        }
    }
}

func fetchImage(for url: String, calling callback: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void = { _ in }) {
    let metadataProvider = LPMetadataProvider()
    guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
        return
    }
    metadataProvider.startFetchingMetadata(for: url) { (metadata, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            assertionFailure("Error")
            return
        }
        
        guard let imageProvider = metadata?.imageProvider else { return }
        
        imageProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { (image, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                // handle error
                return
            }
            if let image = image as? UIImage {
                // do something with image
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    callback(image)
                }
            } else {
                print("no image available")
            }
        }
    }
}

@main
struct MyWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "Widget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(kind: kind, intent: ConfigurationIntent.self, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            WidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
    }
}
```

Comment: this works! would you know how to amend this if your Model is a multidimensional one like a JSON Array which has a list of urls where you want to fetch the images for?
struct Model: TimelineEntry{
    
    var date: Date
    var widgetData: [JSONModel]
}

Comment: I am not quite sure if I'm getting you right...You want to fetch a constant URL that responds with a JSON containing a list of n URLs to some images and you want to show those n images on your widget? In that case you still have to do all of the work in `getSnapshot` or `getTimeline`. First fetch the json using something like `fetchJSON(url, onComplete: { imageURLs in ... }). Inside the callback you then have to use the `fetchImage` and count how many callbacks have already fired. Once your counter reaches imageURLs.count you are done and can call `getSnapshot`'s `completion` callback.

Comment: Yes this is what i am trying to do. I have the data containing the urls in JSON fetched in the getTimeline and for those urls i need the images. i have added var images: [UIImage] to my Model/TimelineEntry and before posting the data in the timeline completion i am trying to update the Model for each url to fetch the image.

Comment: could you look at my code for me and fix it? you can reach me on twitter (at) a3igner

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/theMomax/1daf5033e5e94306ed303ed03cb297c3)'s some code that should fit your requirements, but you'll have to adapt it to your business logic yourself.