# Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service

Tags: ios, webkit

When I using **WKWebView**, I receive the following error `Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service`

I have checked cookies as proposed in [Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811887/could-not-signal-service-com-apple-webkit-webcontent), however it doesn't help

[com.apple.WebKit.WebContent drops 113 error: Could not find specified service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44585980/com-apple-webkit-webcontent-drops-113-error-could-not-find-specified-service) doesn't help too.

What should I do to solve the questions

Comment: Have you figured this out? The same is happening to me...

Comment: Happening to me too. I have two identical projects (forking one on my machine) and one works. The other gets this error. The code is still identical. XCode is hilarious.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was launching a WKWebView and displaying a website. 
Then (within 25 seconds) I deallocated the WKWebView. But 25-60 seconds after launching the WKWebView I received this "113" error message. 
I assume the system was trying to signal something to the WKWebView and couldn't find it because it was deallocated.

The fix was simply to leave the WKWebView allocated.

Comment: how do you do that? can you explain

Comment: When you instantiate the WKWebView you set it equal to a global variable in a class that is not deallocated:            @interface MyViewController (){
       WebViewer *myWebViewer;
}

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though when running the app in debug, something happens and it loses connection in the middle of making a connection, but then it regains connection but it's too late. So the app just stalls, the connection doesn't fail because the app think it's making one, so it's stuck in limbo not knowing what to do.

Run the app outside of debug and keep doing the same thing you were doing when you got the error and see if you can recreate this, bug.

If not, then try to turn off your wifi/data as soon as you go to connect to a webservice and see if you are able to recreate it, if so then you know that it's due to connectivity and not your code itself.

Comment: This answer is right but I would like to find a better solution